# Validating Credit Card Numbers Hackerrank

Tags: python, validation

This ts My code of Validating Number Cards In Hackerrank I tried many times To Know where is the error but i didn't find Also it work well for single input But if i entered many inputs ex:5, it give me "**Index out of range**"
here is the code

```
def cal_Redundant(string):                
    """To calculate Redundant String in list """  
   for i in range(len(string)) :        

     if string[i] == string[i+1] and i<=len(string):
        return False 
    else :
        return True
def Validate(string):

 

divide_str_if_slash=string.split('-')  
df=cal_Redundant(divide_str_if_slash)   
divide_str2=[string[x:x+4] for x in range(0,len(string),4)]  
df2=cal_Redundant(divide_str2)   
if len(string) == 19 :  
    for i in range(len(string)) :  
        if string[0] in ['4','5','6'] \  
            and  string[4] == '-' and string[9] == '-' and string[14] == '-' \  
                and 48 <= ord(string[i])  <= 57  \  
                    and df :  
            print('Valid')  
            break   
        else :  
            print('Invalid')  
            break  
elif len(string) == 16 :  
    for i in range(len(string)) :  
        if string[0] in ['4','5','6'] \  
                and 48 <= ord(string[i])  <= 57 \  
                    and df2 :  
            print('Valid')  
            break   
        else :  
            print('Invalid')  
            break  
else :  
    print("InValid")  

if __name__=="__main__":  
    cards = list()  
    for i in range(int(input())):  
        cards.append(input())  
    
    for c in cards:  
        Validate(c)
```

Comment: `string[i] == string[i+1]` will fail if you pass a string of 1 character. You should stop the code from going further if it isnt a valid credit card format.

Comment: Show a sample input that doesn't work and show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: i do this case if it's length less or more than 16,19 so i case of you enter one character it go to invalid directly

Comment: i really don't Know a case i try the all the cases that given one by one they work well , but if i try all together it don't @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 0):

The way you're checking for use of hyphens is flawed. Consider this invalid credit card number:

```
4567-4567-4567- 4567
```

Note the embedded space. So, whilst there are three hyphens, the total length is greater than 19.

You may find this more robust:

```
def Validate(cc):
    if '-' in cc:
        tokens = cc.split('-')
        if len(tokens) != 4 or any(len(t) != 4 for t in tokens):
            return False
        cc = ''.join(tokens)
    for c in set(cc):
        if c*4 in cc:
            return False
    return len(cc) == 16 and cc.isdigit() and cc[0] in {'4','5','6'}
```

Comment: No it isn't , if the string is more than 19 it will immediately go to invalid case of else  statement

Comment: i tried the case you post and works as expected

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you. It got accepted in Hacker rank

Get connected on YouTube : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGyPMPll4hebbl_cgVy5zlw

**Question :**  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-credit-card-number/problem?isFullScreen=true

```
import re

N = int(input())

for _ in range(N):

    S = input()

    chk_length = 0 if len(S) in [16,19] else 1

    m = re.search(r"^[456]\d{15}$|^[456]\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}", S)

    if m and chk_length == 0:
        if re.search(r"(\d)\1{3,}", S.replace('-', '')):
            print('Invalid')
        else:
            print('Valid')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

**Result :**

[image: Solution]

**Try this test cases:**

```
3695-7963-  5827-75
4143-4672-8798-2968-2968
6865---------------3965---------------1564-------------2918
4123456789123456
5123-4567-8912-3456
61234-567-8912-3456
4123356789123456
5133-3367-8912-3456
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456
6865396515642918
```

Comment: Why is *chk_length* a list?

Comment: @DarkKnight : Thanks for predicting. Yes we can achieve without list. My bad ... ;)